# Jenkins : [parameterized-trigger] Properties file

Tags: jenkins, parameterized

I am using "Parameterized Trigger Plugin" to trigger child job. I am using "parametres from properties file" and in the "Use properties from file" in need to pass the name of the file as a variable...I get this error.

```
[parameterized-trigger] Properties file $propeties_file did not exist.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5L6Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the `?` you will see the usage / syntax for the property file:

> Comma seperated list of absolute or relative paths to file(s) that
>   contains the parameters for the new project. Relative paths are
>   originated from the workspace. The file should have KEY=value pairs,
>   one per line (Java properties file format). Backslashes are used for
>   escaping, so use "\\" for a single backslash. Current build
>   paramenters and/or environment variables can be used in form: ${PARAM}
>   or $PARAM.

So your file needs to exist and you should put the path to the file to where you are putting your `$properties_file` - I don't believe it will accept a variable, you should put the file name in there.

Answer (score 0):

A sample pipeline to trigger parameterize build using parameters from the properties file

```
pipeline {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage('S1') {
          steps {
            echo 'In S1'
            sh '''

        echo "param1=value1" > my.properties
        echo "param2=value2" >> my.properties
        '''
      }
    }
    stage('s2'){
      steps {
        script {
          def props = readProperties  file:"${WORKSPACE}/my.properties"
          build job: 'called_job', parameters: props.collect {string(name: it.key, value: it.value)}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In Stage S1 I am generating a sample file and in Stage S2 reading the same properties and passing param1=value1 and param2=value2 to the called pipeline. Assuming that called_job has param1 and param2 as String parameters